# Не получается отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть простая форма, которую получилось отправить, но не пойму почему происходит перезагрузка страницы? ajax же должен отправлять без перезагрузки. Что я делаю не так? Кроме того в `url` помещается все данные из формы даже после перезагрузки. Вообщем, что то идет не так, а что именно не могу разобраться, кто может, подскажите плиз...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#form").submit(function() {

        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "send.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function() {
                alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
            }
        })
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="contact-form" name="myForm" id="form">
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <input class="contact-form__input" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="ФИО">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <input class="contact-form__input" type="tel" name="Phone" id="tel" placeholder="+38 (099) 000-00-00">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <input class="contact-form__input" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <select class="contact-form__input" name="Select">
            <option>Тестирование сайта</option>
            <option>Тестирование моб. приложения</option>
            <option>Тестирование прототипа</option>
            <option>Тестирование веб-сервиса</option>
            <option>Другое</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <textarea class="contact-form__textarea" name="Message"></textarea>
          <input class="btn-main contact-form__submit" type="submit" value="Бесплатная Консультация">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет: `preventDefault();`

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    // e - от слова event, текущее событие
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "send.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(e),
        success: function(r) {
            // r - от слова response - ответ сервера
            alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
        }
    })
});
```

Теперь поясню:
Вы слушаете событие формы `submit`. Как оно работает обычно? Перезагружает страницу и грубо говоря отправляет данные из формы. Так вот нужно перехватить стандартное поведение браузера такое как перезагрузка и отправка данных, и вместо него сделать что-то своё, в данном случае: послать AJAX, для этого и передаём в функцию само событие `e`, и делаем ему `preventDefault();`

Ещё подробнее тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action

Comment: Но в таком случае, данные в форме остаются. Мне нужно будет очистить все поля формы после отправки? Специально?
А почему в url передаются параметры? Это особенность ajax?

Comment: В урл ничего передаваться не должно, когда отправляем аяксом, форму очищаем руками примерно так `$('form').trigger('reset');`

Comment: Спасибо что так объяснили. Еще хочу уточнить, это нормальная практика? Я почему то сразу подумал что это кастыль

Comment: @max практика нормальная, всё впорядке.